# TypeError at /listing: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to make an auction site and I'm having an issue changing the bid in the Bids model for a particular Auctionlisting object when POST data is submitted.

```
class Bids(models.Model):
    minimum_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=False)
    allbids = []
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    allbids.append(bid)
    numBids = len(allbids)


    def __str__(self):
        if self.bid == None:
            return f"Minimum Bid: ${self.minimum_bid}" 
        else:
            return f"Highest Bid: ${self.bid}"
    

    def save(self, userbid, object):
        item = self.objects.get(pk=object)
        item.bid = userbid
        item.save()
```

Here is my AuctionListing model:

```
class AuctionListing(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=137)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Category.CHOICES, default="Men")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    bid = models.OneToOneField(Bids, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.category}: {self.title}"
```

Here is how I'm submitting the data in my views:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if "userbid" in request.POST:
        try:
            userbid = AuctionListing.objects.get(pk = request.GET.get("listing"))
            userbid.bid = Bids.save(userbid=1000,object=object)
            userbid.save()

        except IntegrityError:
            pass
```

Comment: add the error massage

Comment: You are calling `save` on the model class and not the instance. Or if you are creating, it should be `Bids.objects.create(userbid=1000,object=object)`

Comment: Exactly where is `object` coming from here? Is this a `Bids` object, or something else. THe `allbids` will *not* update the list with `bid` objects, hence that makes not much sense, and I would strongly advise *not* to override the `.save()` method if you alter its signature.

Comment: @RithikTank: you should not do that in the model but in the view, not by overriding the save method, but by implementing logic to alter an object in the view. It is also unclear where `object` originates from here in your view.

Comment: But editing data in general is often error-prone due to *race conditions*. It is also unclear why your `Bids` objects have a `minimum_bid` field. Normally that should be something related to the item you are bidding on, not the bid itself.

Comment: my object originates from GET data that is in my URL -> request.GET.get("listing") which is the pk of the AuctionListing objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modeling is quite odd. An `AuctionListing` refers to a `Bids` model, but it makes not much sense to do that. In case each `AcutionListing` has a `Bids` object and vice-versa, it is more sensical to just add the data to the `AuctionListing` itself.

Furthermore you do not store the individual bids. If later the auction is closed, how will you know who made the highest bid? Your `Bids` model also creates a list, and appends the `bid` *field* to that, but that is the only item it will contain. The logic in the class is only evaluated *once*: when the class is constructed, so from the moment the class has been interpreted, the `bid` and `numBids` do not make much sense anymore.

The `Bids` also contain a field `minimum_bid`, but this is information related to the object people are bidding on, not a bid itself.

A more sensical modeling is that you have an `AuctionListing` to present objects on which one can bid. Per `AuctionListing` there can be multiple `Bid`s, one can then determine the lowest bid by annotating, or making queries. In that case the two models are thus defined as:

```
class AuctionListing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=137)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Category.CHOICES, default='Men')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    minimum_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.category}: {self.title}'

    def get_largest_bit(self):
        return self.bids.order_by('-bid').first()
```

Then you can define a `Bid` model with a `ForeignKey` to the `AuctionList`: the item that people can bid on:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        AuctionListing,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='bids'
    )
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

In your view, you can then make a bid on the `AuctionList` item with as primary key `pk` with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def make_bid(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(AuctionList, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bid_value = request.POST['bid']  # retrieve the bid value from somewhere
        if bid_value < item.minimum_bid:
            # do something, report an error
            # …
        else:
            Bid.objects.create(item_id=pk, bid=bid_value)
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        # …
    # …
```